# Variable declared in controller with 'var' but referenced as scope in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm implementing a module called ngTable which you can find [here](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1).

[In the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISa4xg?p=info) for example one, the following in the controller caught my eye:

A variable is declared in the controller:

```
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}, ....
```

Data is referenced later in the controller

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

And in the view, data is referenced with a $ prefix in an ngRepeat:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

How is the view aware of data even though data was not declared as a scope variable? What is going on in this ngTableParams that I'm missing?

Maybe I need to do more research on $defer.resolve?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/ng-table.js#L411, `ngTable` has a reference of the controller's `$scope` and adds `$data` to it.